# How to send a message to the phone number when the data will be updated in Realtime Database?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying that, In Firebase Realtime Database, our machine number is saved under the user's phone number, The details of the machine are being updated all the time, For example, the machine is now on or off, what the temperature is? etc. Now I want when the data is updated in Realtime database then a message will be sent to the phone number of the owner of that machine. How is this possible?